# Exponential Word Problem $s(x)=5000-4000e^{-x}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with this word problem. Much appreciated.

Sales of a new model of word processor are approximated by $S(x)=5000 - 4000e^{-x}$, where $x$ represents the number of years that the word processor has been on the market, and $S(x)$ represents sales in thousands of dollars. When will sales reach $4,500,000$?

Comment: You are looking for $x$ such that $5000 - 4000e^{x}=4,500,000$, that is $5-4e^x=4,500$. Does it admit a solution?

Comment: @OlivierOloa It should be $5000-4000e^x=4500$, as $S(x)$ is in thousands of dollars. Even with that equation, the solution for $x$ doesn't make sense (in terms of the problem) as it is a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve it straightforward as below.
\begin{align}
5000000-4000000e^x=4500000
&&&\Longrightarrow&& 4000000e^x=500000\\
&&&\Longrightarrow&& e^x=\frac{1}{8}\\
&&&\Longrightarrow&& x=-\ln 8.
\end{align}
That is, $\ln 8$ years ago from the present.